# Null check on a COleVariant

Tags: c++, variant, type-mismatch

Is it possible to do a null check on a COleVariant or at the very least check if it's type is set to VT_NULL? I see that there is a ChangeType() method but was hoping I could somehow figure out what the current type was before I attempt to change the type as changing from VT_NULL to VT_INT throws a type mismatch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the vt member.

Comment: +1.  Yes, sucky documentation.  COleVariant inherits from VARIANT so all the VARIANT members are available.

Comment: Took a lot of searching before I actually found that, oddly enough not mentioned on MSDN at all under COleVariant members.